# kineticjs add element to stage

Tags: javascript, jquery, kineticjs

I'm new to JS and KineticJS, and was wondering if someone could help me understand how the Kinetic.Stage node works. I've used [this tutorial](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/labs/html5-canvas-drag-and-drop-resize-and-invert-images/) as a starting place -- but would like to be able to append objects (such as new Kinetic.Text() or new Kinetic.Group()) to the existing stage on click of a button.

An example of what I'm trying to do is have a form next to the canvas that allows a user to enter text, click "go", and have the "text that they entered" appear inside the canvas.

I've tried to declare "var stage" inside the document.ready and in global scope, thinking that I could access the stage from within a function, for instance:

```
function writeTextToStage(stage) {
     var text = new Kinetic.Text({
       x: 190,
       y: 15,
       text: 'Simple Text',
       fontSize: 30,
       fontFamily: 'Calibri',
       textFill: 'green'
     });
      var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
      layer.add(text);
      stage.add(layer);
      stage.draw();
}

window.onload = function(){
    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
        container: "designer",
        width: 578,
        height: 520
    });
    var go = document.getElementById('go');
    go.addEventListener('mousedown', writeTextToCanvas(stage);
};
```

Anyways, if the "stage" object is declared within another function -- "initStage()", is it possible to get the stage node after it has been initialized in order to append things to it? I've tried accessing it via the DOM element, $('kineticjs-content').children()[0].

Please assist. The documentation on kineticjs.com is not very verbose.
Thanks!

Comment: Last line missing paren - `go.addEventListener('mousedown', writeTextToCanvas(stage));`

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the help, but that code was more-or-less just an example of what i'm trying to do, not the code I'm using. I'm more curious if it's possible to get the stage and add layers to it after it has been created.

Comment: what do you want to append to the stage and why? The code above looks fine (except for the missing parenthesis), so not sure what are you trying to do here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the layer outside your function, then in your function just add the text to the layer...

```
function AddText() {
   var text = new Kinetic.Text({
   ...
   });
  layer.add(text);
}
```